# Deploy WAR file to Openshift without using GIT?

Tags: java, git, tomcat, jboss, openshift

I want to upload a WAR file to my **Openshift** account , but it forces me 
to use GIT ot GITHUB ([here](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear)). Please forgive me for saying this , but this is very very annoying .

Is there any way upload a WAR file straight to my application without using some third party ?

My application (in the Openshift) consists of : Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0), MySQL 5.5 .

Much appreciated

Comment: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear : There is a method to deploy war using SCP/SFTP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please follow the instructions in the following link

https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

More details :

You can use like this :

Hit `git` and log into the git bash , and then do this:

```
scp <your local file name> <your hash number>@<your app name>-<your domain name>.rhcloud.com:~/<app name>/data/
```

example:

```
scp hello.csv 87b95e67477f442c9356a4ae49cd7c9e@cdapp-music.rhcloud.com:~/cdapp/data/
```

External Sources : from [here](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/can-i-copy-files-from-my-workstation-to-openshift-using-scp)

Comment: @BobMalooga: I fixed his comment , and tested it on my machine with the example I've added , and it works OK.

Answer (score 5):

You may refer https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-deployment-options.html

Steps:

1. `git clone` to download the source code
2. remove  `src` and `pom.xml` from repo and push
3. Use `Win Scp` / `FileZilla` to log into your app
4. Paste `ROOT.war` here `/var/lib/openshift/{APP_ID}/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps`

or simply `app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps` from the landing directory.

Comment: this does not answer the question, as it uses Git.

Comment: No it does not use git for source version control. It just says get the code via git and delete the [dot] POM file from repo. Otherwise it will keep on picking maven builds.

Comment: @zygimantus I have never tried wildfly. It should be similar, directory structure may vary slightly.