# How to deploy a war file in Openshift JBoss AS ?

Tags: java, jboss, openshift

How to deploy a war file in Openshift JBoss AS  ? Is it the same as the deployment with an Openshift Tomcat Server or there are some differences in settings ?

Comment: refer to 
https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/deployment-options.html

Would suggest to use git for it rather than deploying prebuild war file,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy WAR file to Openshift without using GIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264517/deploy-war-file-to-openshift-without-using-git)

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you show some more work?  What errors have you gotten?